# Simple JavaScript App with .push & forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

here is the issue, trying to use forEach specifically instead of a for loop to create a note app and print to the DOM, but the problem I have is my code appendChild with the array and it gets all messed up, i was looking into different ways to do it but have given up tonight.

Here it is

```js
const notes = [];
function myArray(a) {
  a = document.getElementById("txt").value
  notes.push(a);

  notes.forEach(function (item) {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    document.body.appendChild(p)
    p.innerHTML += item;
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myArray()">Note</button>
<input id="txt" type="text">
```

Comment: What does "all messed up" mean?

Comment: since you add to the notes array every time, the list just gets longer, so you add 1 item, it output 1 item, add another item, and you add both first and second item, and a third item, you'll add first second and third to the dom

Comment: Use another container you can empty before doing the loop. Or just append each single note as you create it instead of doing the loop

Comment: You are calling `myArray` from button onclick without argument(s).
On the other hand, your function `myArray` is excpecting an argument which is immediately gets run-over.
I think you just need to remove the argument `a` from the function declaration.
I'd append the `p`s into an element, a div, and clear it each time, or, just append the last/newest value of input.
If you are going to remove items from the array, use the clearing each time approach.
I'd call the function `addInput`...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to push the item in  array and then iterate it to create note. In that case after every addition you have to remove previous elements otherwise it will result in duplication of same note. You can first append the element in the dom then add it to the array for any future reference

```js
const notes = [];

function myArray(a) {
  a = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  const txtNode = document.createTextNode(a);
  p.appendChild(txtNode);
  document.body.appendChild(p)
  notes.push(a);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myArray()">Note</button>
<input id="txt" type="text">
```

If you wish iterate the array and append the result then first clear the container which will hold all the `p` then iterate the array to show the result

```js
const notes = [];

function myArray() {
  const a = document.getElementById("txt").value
  notes.push(a);
  const getContainer = document.getElementById('noteContainer');
  getContainer.innerHTML = ''
  notes.forEach(function(item) {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    getContainer.appendChild(p)
    p.innerHTML += item;
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myArray()">Note</button>
<input id="txt" type="text">
<div id='noteContainer'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution with note onclick to remove from html and from array, and enter acts as clicking add:

```js
var notes=[];

function addNote() {
  var id=new Date().valueOf().toString();
  var text=document.getElementById("noteInput").value;
  notes.push({id:id, text:text});
  displayNotes();
}

function displayNotes() {
  var div=document.getElementById("notesDiv");
  div.innerHTML="";
  notes.forEach(note=> {
    var p=document.createElement("p");
    p.id=note.id;
    p.textContent=note.text;
    p.setAttribute("onclick", "removeNote(\""+note.id+"\")");
    div.append(p);
  });
}

function removeNote(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).remove();
  var index=-1;
  for(var i=0; i<notes.length && index==-1; i++)
    if(notes[i].id==id) index=i;
  if(index!=-1) notes.splice(index, 1);
  if(notes.length==0) document.getElementById("notesDiv").textContent="Notes will appear here";
}
```

```css
.notes {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
Note: <input id="noteInput" onchange="addNote()">
<button onclick="addNote()">Add</button><br>
Notes:<br>
<div id="notesDiv" class="notes">Notes will appear here</div>
```